# count unique visitors and reset the counter everyday without using database

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a visitors counter in php....

I don't know how to recount or reset the counter everyday since the available counter only count once

My code looks like this now:

Not sure if this code is working but asking for some idea or suggestion. 
Thank you

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");//grab timezone
$now = date("H:i");
echo $now;
echo "<br>";

if($now == "00:00"){//when the clock is 00:00 count will be 0 again
    $count = 0;
}
?>
<?php
session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) { // It's the first visit in this session
    $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r");
    if(!$handle){
        echo "Could not open the file" ;
    }
    else {
        $counter = ( int ) fread ($handle,20) ;
        fclose ($handle) ;
        $counter++ ;
        echo" <p> Visitor Count: ". $counter . " </p> " ;
        $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "w" ) ;
        fwrite($handle,$counter) ;
        fclose ($handle) ;
        $_SESSION['counter'] = $counter;
    }

} else { // It's not the first time, do not update the counter but show the total hits stored in session
    $counter = $_SESSION['counter'];
    echo" <p> Visitor Count: ". $counter . " </p> " ;
}
?>
```

My goal is to display the number of visitor everyday.
p/s: Some code is from stackoverflow.

Comment: Google Analytics is the best tool i think for this purpose! isnt it?

Comment: Do you mean 'reset' instead of 'recount'? If not, what do you mean by 'recount'?

Comment: I don't understand your goal : have statistics per day ?

Comment: @devpro: Google Analytics is the most used, not the best. It exists to give Google access to what people do on the web. If you want a simple visitor counter it is not the correct tool.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes reset! my bad.

Comment: @JoffreySchmitz I want to display the number of visitor everyday

Answer (score 0):

Your code would only have a chance of working if someone visits your site at exactly 00:00 server time.

You'll need a [cronjob](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/) or similar that resets the counter in the .txt at 00:00 independent of page visits.

Comment: This can be done without a cronjob. If you also store in the `"counter.txt"` file to which date a count applies, then a new date will always start at zero.

Comment: True, this way you also have a way to compare visits per day, upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the current day in the file. When you retrieve the data, if the date in the file is different, it is the first visit on the current day, and you can reset the counter :

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");//grab timezone
$today = date("Y-m-d"); // get current date

session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) { // It's the first visit in this session
    $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r");
    if(!$handle){
        echo "Could not open the file" ;
    }
    else {
        // retrieve the data
        $line = fread($handle,20) ;
        fclose ($handle) ;
        $parts = explode(' ', $line);
        $date = $parts[0]; // retrieve date in file
        $counter = intval($parts[1]); // retrieve visit in file

        // reset if first visit at a new day
        if($date != $today)
        {
            $counter = 0 ;
        }

        // save the new date/counter data
        $counter++ ;
        echo" <p> Visitor Count: ". $counter . " </p> " ;
        $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "w" ) ;

        $newdata= $today . ' ' . $counter ; // put today + counter in the file
        fwrite($handle,$newdata) ;
        fclose ($handle) ;
        $_SESSION['counter'] = $counter;
    }

} else { // It's not the first time, do not update the counter but show the total hits stored in session
    $counter = $_SESSION['counter'];
    echo" <p> Visitor Count: ". $counter . " </p> " ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this on the stackoverflow.

It works exactly like how I want.

Thank you for helping me.

```
<?php
$filename = date("Ymd") . "_counter.txt";
$seenFilename = date("Ymd") . '_seen_ip.txt';

$ips = array();
if (file_exists($seenFilename))
{
    $ips = file($seenFilename);
    $ips = array_map('trim', $ips);
}

if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ips))
{
    $visits = 0;
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $visits = file_get_contents($filename);
    }

    file_put_contents($filename, ++$visits);
    $data = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . PHP_EOL;
    $fp = fopen($seenFilename, 'a');
    fwrite($fp, $data);
}
$fn = fopen($filename, "r");
$result = fgets($fn);
echo $result;
fclose($fn);
?>
```

p/s: Some code is from stackoverflow.